# how do i get fix this so it changes the entire font case of a csv to lower?

Tags: python, csv

I keep getting "NameError: name '[file name]' is not defined" after entering "process_csv(b.csv, b2.csv)" in IDLE. i'm not sure what to fix. any ideas?

```
import csv

def process_csv(file_name, new_file_name):
    '''Reads from external CSV file.
    puts each number in lowercase.
    Writes values to new CSV file.
    '''
    file1 = open(file_name, 'r')
    file2 = open(new_file_name, 'w', newline='')

    data = csv.reader(file1)
    new_data = csv.writer(file2)

    for line in data:                   
        row = []                        
        for item in line:               
            if item.isalpha():        
                item = item.lower()     
            row.append(item)            
        new_data.writerow(row)          

    file1.close()
    file2.close()

    print('File processed.')
```

Comment: Can you show the call to `process_csv` and the exact error message?

Comment: are you providing the full path to b.csv or are you just using b.csv?  You need the full path

Comment: sure!  `process_csv(budget.csv, b2.csv)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    process_csv(budget.csv, b2.csv)
NameError: name 'budget' is not defined`

Comment: @PyNEwbie the python file and the csv are in the same directory. do i still need the path?

Comment: yes and quotation marks 'c:\\budget.csv','c:\\b2.csv') it needs to be the full path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need quotation marks around the file names:

```
"b.csv" and "b2.csv"
```